# Installing win8 on newer drive while keeping old one for data

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, hard-drive

I have a 8 y/o Samsung 120Gb drive [still running strong] running Windows 7. I've recently purchased Windows 8 and a new WD 1TB drive that is much faster.

I'd like to install Win8 from my USB drive onto this newer drive but not lose my files from my old drive. Basically use it as a data drive.

is it safe to unplug my old drive, install windows 8 on the new drive and set it as the primary boot disk? What happens to the MBR on the old drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data will be safe and you are good to go with your plan. MBR in the old drive will remain inactive until you make that HDD as primary boot disk.When you make your new HDD as your first boot device, bootloader will be looking for MBR in partitions marked as active in you new HDD.